# Domination of functions in $L^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose there is a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ in $L^1(\Omega)$ with $f_n \to f$ a.e. in $\Omega$. But, also suppose that $\nexists \ g \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $|f_n| \leqslant g$ a.e on $\Omega$, $\forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}$. That is, there is no function $g \in L^1(\Omega)$ that dominates the sequence $\{f_n\}$. The last statement implies that $\nexists \ g \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $\int_{\Omega} |f_n(x)| dx \leqslant \int_{\Omega} |g(x ) |dx \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

As I tried to argue:

$\forall \ g \in L^1(\Omega)$ $\exists \ n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and set $M_g \subseteq \Omega$ with $\mu(M_g) > 0; |f_{n_0}(x)| > g(x) \ \forall \ x \in M$. So in particular, $\int_{M} |f_{n_0(x)}| dx > \int_M |g(x)| dx$. Does this prove what you want or are there any inconsistencies? Tanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see how the estimation of your last integral over $M$ tells us anything. Also the answer to your question is "no":

A function $g \in L^1(\Omega)$ such that $\int_{\Omega}\lvert  f_n \rvert\leq \int_{\Omega}\lvert g \rvert$ where  $f_n$ is not $L^1$-dominated a.e. can exist. Choose $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n(x) = \exp((x-n)^2)$. Because of (substitute $x-n=y$)
$$
\int_{\Omega} f_n(x) ~\mathrm{d}x=  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(-x^2)~\mathrm{d}x < \infty,
$$
dominated convergence thm very clearly does not apply (pointwise limit of $f_n$ is $\infty$ while the integral stays finite independently of $n$). So $f_n$ can not be dominated by an $L^1$-function. Moreover, we can set $h(x) = \chi_{[-1, 1]}(x) + \chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1, 1]} (x)\exp(-x^2)$ and get
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert f_n(x) \rvert~\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp(-x^2)~\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert h(x) \rvert~\mathrm{d}x < \infty.
$$

The difference between a bound of the integral and the bound a.e. is that integrals over the entire real line are invariant under translation whereas a pointwise bound is just that - a bound at (in this case almost) every point (and those can't be moved).